# How to use timer in java without using thread?

Tags: java, wait

How can I make a java program wait X seconds without using`Thread.sleep`?

```
public class newClass{
     public static void main(String[] args){
           for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
               //Wait X second 
               System.out.println("Hello");
           }
     }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

**I need the program won't freeze while it's counting**

Comment: `wait()` to be `notified` by whom?

Comment: "Make program wait" is exactly what `sleep` does. So what is your issue?

Comment: Are you asking about busy waiting?

Comment: What do you reckon the difference between waiting and sleeping is?

Comment: What is the supposed difference between wait/sleep?

Comment: What would you code do if appropriate code was inserted at the comment? Would it print "Hello" 10 times and then what?

Comment: use `while` loop and system current time.

Comment: Busy wait and constant check for `System.currentTimeMillis`, maybe?

Comment: I mean that the software will not Go away to sleep so I can continue working on it without having to wait until the time is over count

Comment: use a lock, lock it, and then tryLock for 10 seconds ;)  terrible solution though - just use sleep.  Please explain to us why sleep is not a viable solution in your case.  Once we know more, we can better help.

Comment: "continue working on it"? As in, continue editing the code? Your program runs in its own process, sure you can go on editing your code.

Comment: I am a software programmer camp, each child has 10 minutes to play on a computer and I want to program all children want to enter the list put his name program to count 10 minutes, once the program has finished counting window pops up that says that the line of the next child arrived

Comment: Look guys it hards to me to explain because i'm from israel and i don't know very well English so its little hard for me.

Comment: Use a SwingTimer that does something after 10 minutes - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: "a window pops up" sounds like you're doing a GUI application. If it's Swing, then you want to *schedule* that popup appearing with the `SwingTimer` class. If it's not Swing, the generic mechanism is offered by the `ScheduledExecutorService`, but you'll have to take care of executing GUI operations on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java's Timer and TimerTask class for this.

```
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;
 public class newClass extends TimerTask{
      int i = 10;
      static Timer timer;

      @Override
      public void run(){
           System.out.println("hello");
           i--;
           if (i == 0)
               timer.cancel();

      }

      public static void main(String[] args){
           TimerTask timerTask = new newClass();
           timer = new Timer(false);
           timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 5 * 1000);
      }
 }
```

And Timer works on its own thread in the background so it won't freeze up the rest of your program!

Comment: How can i make it write 10 times "Hello"?
Can you change the code that it will do that?

Comment: The TimerTask should repeat at a fixed interval until you call cancel(), so this code should repeat 10 times. Is it not working that way?

Comment: No i don't know why because i never used code like this

Comment: Ok, just change the line "timer = new Timer(true)" to "timer = new Timer(false)" and tell me if that works

Comment: Yes it works !!
Can you explain the code to me?
With comments it also good :)

Comment: If you were wondering, the problem was that Timer's thread was a [daemon thread](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/daemon.html) which means it killed itself after the main method ended, and thus stopped the timer from repeating

Comment: Ok so check out ian's link about threads. Basically because Timer runs on a separate thread, it runs as it's own parallel process, which means it doesn't interfere with any other processes. When you call schedulAtFixedRate, you provide an instance of TimerTask as a parameter. In this case it's an instance of newClass. Timer then calls the run() method in that class after the amount of time specified in the parameters. Check out this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for more info.

Comment: One more question I want to put your code in my software and don't know where.

Comment: I guess I'd have to see your code to know for sure but what I would do is create a separate class that extends TimerTask and overrides the run method, and then put the stuff that was in the main method wherever you need your program to wait

Comment: Im going to add something to my question up there ^^ so it will be helpfull if you help me :)

Comment: I don't have Skype but you can just email it to me at dlschon0@gmail.com

Comment: Ok i`m sending the email now :)

Comment: Just add a new class called MyTimerTask or whatever and have it extend TimerTask. In that class, override the "run" method. In the main class, change "new newClass" to "new MyTimerTask" (or whatever you decide to call it).

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is that you do not want your program to freeze, consider using threads. This example might be similar to what you want to achieve: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad approach but you can use this:

```
 public class newClass{
      public static void main(String[] args){
           int X = 5;
           for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
               long s = System.nanoTime();
               while( (System.nanoTime() - s) / 1000000000 < X);
               System.out.println("Hello");
           }
      }
 }
```

You can also use

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Comment: This what i mean !
Can you explain it to me?

Comment: In each while loop step, this code controls current time and calculates the elapsed time in seconds. It is bad because it will use CPU cycles, unlike `sleep()` or `wait()` commands, so this is only a bad trick.

Comment: No wait it still make my software freeze :(

Comment: How can i use a wait()?

Comment: If you don't want your program to freeze, you should use a multithread approach like ian mentioned.

Comment: Can you write an example?

Comment: This [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_control.htm) contains what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really looking for is a multi-thread implementation. That is what will allow you to continue interacting with one area of the application while waiting for another to finish processing.

*Edit* 
Ok, after further clarification in the comments, sounds like this is not what you are looking for. Perhaps you can register each child in a HashMap with the time that they started. Then monitor the map to see when time is up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want your program to start, and after X time has elapsed print "Hello" on the output stream?

1. Do as ocozalp suggested
2. Or use the Thread.sleep(x); method

Both options will give you **exactly** the same result, although option 2 is preferred, since you allow the CPU to do something else while your main thread is sleeping, and because using option 1 makes your intention with the program less clear.